# ASP VbScript setting session via HTTP-Request

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, httpwebrequest

I've an ASP VbScript web application requires to preserve status of a checkbox list inside a grid/table across pagination.

I cannot reload page for every click on a check due to long wait time.

Do you think it is possible to make a javascript httprequest to an ASP server page on checkbox click to add or remove the selected record in a session variable?

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to reload (submit) on every click, but on pagination (i.e. the 'pagination' numbers/arrows/letters would submit the form, which would post all the checked boxes. Then you would use this to set the value of 'checked' to the appropriate checkboxes.
Now, if you want to submit to the database every time someone changes a checkbox (so it's kept even if the user does a 'refresh') then best way would be using ajax.

Comment: So you think it is possible to set a session variable with ajax and then retrieve its value!

Comment: not unless you post. From the page, using ajax, you can send a request to an ASP file to set a session, but you won't be able to see the new value. You'd need to post the form, so the ASP would be able to see the new session value; but if you have to post anyway, you don't really need to call another ASP, just post the form when the pagination changes